# Simple PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Another regex problem. This is my HTML input -

```
Some text<br />

        This is really important text <br />

  This is another important text what I need.<br />
```

Please, help me to get the important text from this code. And suggest me some good stuff about reg. expressions, because I feel pretty bad about asking you again.

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to use a regular expression for a language that is not regular! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: What marks the important text? Is it everything after the first `<br>`?

Comment: The question doesn't state what exactly you're wanting to get here. Are you wanting to check if a certain string is in the html? Are you wanting to get the contents of a certain html tag? With either of those questions, cwallenpoole is right, dont use regex.

Comment: I want to get all the content after first <br />

Answer (score 2):

Start with [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). Then take a look at the options available to you [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) (Document Object Model).

Answer (score 0):

You have PHP tagged so are you using the PHP regex function to do the parsing?  If so, I can help you write a reg. expression to match between the 
 tags.  The first match is your first "important text" and the second match is your second.

Try something likes this:

```
$result = preg_match("/<br \/>(.*)<br \/>/", $input, $_matches);
```

Comment: Four problems here: No match at all without dotall modifier. When fixed this, all is matched to the end, because of greedy `.*`. If fixed this, then no second match with `preg_match` (maybe you ment `preg_match_all`?). But it wouldn't match the second "important text" either, because the needed leading `<br />` has been eaten by the first match.